# fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY

Tags: boot, filesystem, fsck

I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7.
I was browsing on FireFox in Ubuntu and all of a sudden I get some error message, so I rebooted.

Now when I try to boot into Ubuntu I get this message:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda6 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda6: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda6 requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you been able to find out the root cause? I experienced exactly the same issue two times within two days using Kubuntu 16.04. Is this some software problem or an indication for defective hardware?

Comment: @Silicomancer, I had this, and other related issues, and it seems quite likely to be related to a failing hard drive. I know my hard drive failed some of the S.M.A.R.T diagnostics right around when this problem occurred. Sometimes a manual 'fsck /dev/sdaX' would fix it, but other times the problem wouldn't be resolved and I'd get a kernel panic on the next boot. I've got a new HD in the mail.

Answer (score 520):

Try this:

```
fsck /dev/sda6
```

(where `/dev/sda6` is the partition mentioned)

And enter Yes (<kbd>y</kbd>) to for each error. Or press <kbd>a</kbd> one time for always-yes.

Then reboot and it should be fine.

Comment: This worked, however in Ubuntu I still get this error message: An error occured, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The Error message was: 'Error: Opening the cache (E:Read error - read (5: Input/output error) E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.) This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

Comment: Ok, so run fsck -a /dev/sda6 and enter Yes to all errors.

Comment: Sorry, I submitted my comment to your answer too quickly by accident, I wasn't done typing yet.

Comment: And when I do apt-get update, it hangs on "Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/pkg.tox.chat_debian_dists_nightly_release_binary-i386_Packages - open (30: Read-only file system)

Comment: Reboot linux, and if all looks good from the booting, then you should go to the apt-get again. If puts you again to busybox terminal, run `fsck -a /dev/sda6` and repair the errors.

Comment: I get fsck from util-linux 2.26.2, /dev/sda6 containsa filesystem with errors, check forced, /dev/sda6: 252365/2445984 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 1433171/9764864 blocks, fsck exited with status code 1, Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboor "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into default mode. root@jordy-desktop:~#

Comment: And when I do fsck -a /dev/sda6 I get "e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting."

Comment: Something really wrong with this ubuntu setup... I don't have any other ideas.. sorry.

Comment: This fucked me! and my workstation goes to read only mood. :(

Comment: do not forget to add `-y` at the end, or else glue your finger pressed to y

Comment: @aditya: You could also press 'a' for always instead of 'y' without using -y

Comment: Okay, this temporarily solves the error but sooner or later I get the same error. What's the problem? Is my disk at fault or Ubuntu itself?

Comment: @Rishabh Agrahari, I think maybe the disk. You should test it with smartd tools.

Comment: where to type `fsck /dev/sda6`??

Comment: @JasomDotnet On your terminal where you see : (initramfs)

Comment: Someone give this user the "Life Saver" badge... Please!! I was worried for a second there 

Comment: @NikolayNikolov I'm facing similar problem again. I forgot how to open `initramfs`. Am I right when I do it way: Advanced options > Recovery... ? Because under this path I see [this](https://i.imgur.com/KtNW3kr.jpg) error. Is there any other way ho to open `initramfs`

Comment: Can anyone explain what are the consequences of facing this error and going through the solution outlined in this answer?

Comment: reboot did not work for me, does anyone know why? I had to manually reboot

Comment: It is work, thank you, but can anyone answer why this error occur?

Comment: I had to run it on both /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda4 for it to work. my sda2 mounted / and sda4 was mounting /home, for some reason both were corrupted

Comment: Thanks (+1), I did then fsck -fy /dev/sdc1 that repaired the fs after then I did exit and it booted again.

Comment: Please help, after running this and typing exit, my laptop says, "Kernel Panic, not syncing. Kill init!" What should I do?

Answer (score 110):

I have noticed that even if you do a `fsck` on the disk the problem may occur again in a few days.

I have found that the problem is worse on SSD disks than the regular HDD disks. I have found some steps that may fix the problem temporarily.

```
fsck -fy /dev/sda1
```

if `sda1` is the right partition - the prompt will tell you exactly which one requires fsck.

After that if the systems boots up you may have another problem with the package management system, so if you open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get update` you may get an error. Do not worry. Run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

My opinion is that there is serious problem in Ubuntu with regard to SSD disks. The community should fix it.

I have found a possible cause of this problem: Probably the system did not shutdown normally.

Comment: After the fsck command type he command exit to force the system to boot again in runlevel 5 or just reboot with init 6.! Your choice.!

Comment: Please [edit] your own posts if you want to add or clarify something.

Comment: I was facing such problem for at least ~10 times for now and actually now I recall that before that I was always installing something. But not every installation followed by such problem.

Comment: Running `fsck` directly didn't work with me. I had to reboot, then choose from the boot menu to run Ubuntu in Safe Mode, and then running `fsck` worked.

Comment: I'm still having these issues occasionally often when I leave ubuntu on overnight - my gut says SSD is worse as well and I've seen a post mentioning some task the OS does for SSD occasionally. Wondering what the solution is...

Answer (score 16):

`UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY` means there is some file system error in the disk. Run the `fsck` command manually. After that it will ask  some more questions - just answer `y` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> and finally reboot the server.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Type `exit` into the prompt, and it should tell you which partition has an error, e.g. `/dev/sda6`. Type `fsck /dev/sdaX -y` where `X` is the partition mentioned in the error. The `-y` flag answers yes to all the prompts it would otherwise have given you - you don't have to use it but it is recommended. Once it has finished, type `reboot` into the prompt, and if prompted, select to continue normal startup.

Comment: this worked. Thanks

Comment: Great! You are a big help man!

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
fsck -y /dev/sda
```

eg:

```
fsck -y /dev/sda1
fsck -y /dev/sda2
```

Answer (score 1):

In  (initramfs) prompt, type the command "fsck" then the path to your hard drive, for example "fsck /deb/sda2" , after add "-y" in order to accept all the fixing errors, for example "fsck /dev/sda2 -y", then the computer will check the errors on the filesystem to repair them.

Comment: The minus y is a very bad idea you wont be able to see what it is fixing and maybe have a clue as to what was or is wrong.

Comment: Indeed might be a bad idea to use the `-y`. In the worst case, it will tell you that you can use `a` to accept all following prompts.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have a recent backup of the partition, you may wanna run a backup first to before doing anything else. Repairing the disk should be safe in most cases, but may be better to have a backup in case things go awry. You will need to mount your backup drive to write to a backup compressed image file for example. Make sure you know which `dev/sdX` is which!

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/username/mydrive
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/user/mydrive
# if= <----- your source to backup goes here!
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 conv=sync,noerror bs=64KB | gzip -c > /media/user/mydrive/system-backup.img.gz
```

Now that you have safely created a backup image, you can safely try to fix disk errors

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda1 # enter y at prompts or a for all
```

Reboot should get you working again. Now make a good habit of regular backups.