# fsck run manually, ubuntu 14.04

Tags: initramfs, ash

UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY : RUN fsck MANUALLY 
The root filesystem on /dev/sdb9 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.21.1(Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built in  shell(ash)

(initramfs)_

Comment: And what is stopping you from doing a manual fsck? ( https://www.google.nl/search?q=linux+manual+fsck&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=D-q_V8TEJKHH8AfbsYTACw )

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Answer (score 0):

then run `fsck /dev/sdb9`

type `y` to fix

once done type exit, it will boot as normal

Answer (score 0):

type
`fsck /dev/sdb9`
and press enter whenever the terminal asks for permission.

Now after the process finishes, type: `reboot`

After rebooting, open the terminal. Make sure you have internet connectivity and type:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now, your system will start normally from now on.