# Problem with starting ubuntu

Tags: startup, system

[image: This appears]

I have a problem while starting ubuntu,

When I start my laptop this appears on my screen

What should I do?

Comment: Run fsck on sda5 i.e `fsck /dev/sda5`. Then just keep accepting(yes or enter) at what ever dialog it gives you, then restart it(type `reboot` if it doesn't reboot automatically).

Answer (score 1):

Give a look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually).

Briefly, the first suggestion is to run

```
fsck /dev/sda5
```

and then reboot.