# after upgrade from ubuntu 14.0 to 16.0 bootscreen comes black on desktop

Tags: boot, upgrade

I was recently on process of upgradation of ubuntu from 14.0 to 16.0. but after up-gradation the boot screen comes with a blank black screen with a cursor blinking.  how can i fix the issue ?

Comment: See this http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162078#162078

Comment: I fixed it. the command " sudo apt-get install lightdm" simply works for me. may be the cause of some broken packages during upgradation.

Comment: I'm glad you got it fixed!

Comment: it was little bit difficult for me , but google helped me to get out of this trouble ! thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Around some time back I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) to Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus). During the upgrade procedure I had erroneously rebooted and had faced a similar problem, although in my case the screen wasn't blank, but instead was [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/697190/606096). Running [this command](https://askubuntu.com/a/697197/606096) helped me restore my system, and after rebooting I finished the remaining upgrade from the Ubuntu Software Centre. I hope this helps