# UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY

Tags: 16.04

```
/dev/sda7 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
 Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda7: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda7 requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

please help

Comment: I've tried    fsck /dev/sda7      and it tell me not found

Comment: try      /sbin/fsck /dev/sda7  -y

Comment: What says `blkid`? Is it still mounted (`umout /dev/sda7`)? When ´sudo fsck.XXX -v -a /dev/sda7´ where XXX depends on the format.

Comment: I've tried  /sbin/fsck /dev/sda7 -y – and still not found!!!

Comment: @musbach i didn't understand, would you clarify PLZ

Comment: Ok, can you please show the output of `blkid` on a terminal? Or try simply `fsck /dev/sda7`

Comment: More details on full e2fsck: http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You would have to use the live-dvd/usb.

You would boot the live-dvd/usb with your PC.

And run fsck from a terminal:

```
sudo -i
umount /dev/sda7 
fsck /dev/sda7 -y
```