# The root filesystem requires manual fsck

Tags: fsck, initramfs

My computer froze. I turned it off and it re-booted with this error:

```
/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced. Inodes that were part of a corrupt orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. Fsck exited with status code 4.
```

[image]

---

Please explain it to me what I need to do simply, as I am really new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](http://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Comment: @DavidFoerster for some reason the called duplicate was closed as unclear and deleted. I've flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: I am marking this question as a duplicate again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the prompt write `fsck -y /dev/sda2` to run manual check on the filesystem. The '-y' option will automatically answer yes to all question.

Comment: Is it: fsck -y/dev/sda?

Comment: Are there any spaces, and should SDA be SDA2?

Comment: `/dev/sda2` not /dev/sda

Comment: OK thanks but is there a space between -y and /dev/sda2 ???

Comment: @Benjamints Yes there is a space there

Comment: It seems `-y` isn't documented?!