# Boot error: "/dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY."

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, boot-repair, initramfs

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox, which has been working for 6 months or so. I am now getting problems when trying to boot into Ubuntu. I get an error message as seen in the [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktqvg.png). I've followed posts saying to type fsck/dev/sda1. After doing so I get onto my Ubuntu desktop, but if I try to open an application, the screen freezes and puts me back into the log in screen.

I've made a short video showing all of this:
https://youtu.be/o4TlD7i3PD0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The root filesystem requires manual fsck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890501/the-root-filesystem-requires-manual-fsck)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a hardware failure.

You can try starting in single user, check with `debugfs -w /dev/sda1` and then `lsdel` to see the deleted inodes.

Also `hdparm -T /dev/sda` to see if everything runs smoothly.