# the root filesystem requires a manual fsck

Tags: 14.04, boot, fsck

When I try to boot my laptop, I get this message:
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _

when I write: fsck/dev/sd1
I get the message: /bin/sh:fsck/dev/sd1

What shall I do???

Comment: you need a space and drive desegnation `fsck /dev/sda1`

Comment: I suggest you run fsck from a live CD as well. In addition, as a caution, when you have to run fsck manually it is sometimes a sign your hard drive is failing. If you have not done so already, make a back up of any data you do not wish to loose ASAP, and run smartmontools - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: @Panther That would be an good answer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Answer (score 3):

You need space between command and argument. The command is `fsck`, and the argument is the device `/dev/sda1`. Try `fsck /dev/sda1`. Note that there is a space between `fsck` and `/dev/sda1`.

Additionally you may want to use `fsck -y /dev/sda1` to answer yes automatically to any questions fsck asks.

Comment: thank you, I've done so. Now my desktop is black?? I wait

Comment: Nothing happens...what shall I do now? Help!!

Comment: Now I see: /dev/sda1:***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

Comment: and /dev/sda1: 2353330/4825088 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 17131265/19277824 blocks

Comment: Then you have fixed your file system. Run fsck once more, and reboot.

Comment: Now I see: e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015) /dev/sda1: clean 2353330/4825088 files,  17131265/19277824 blocks

Comment: Just reboot then. You can do this by pressing Ctrl-D, or typing `reboot`

Comment: it rebootet but I cannot open anything

Comment: now I can open nearly everything, firefox has a problem

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!!! I must still learn a lot about ubuntu

Comment: If you have a problem with Firefox, I suggest you make a new question for it :)

Comment: sorry, after rebooting I couldn't start any program. That's why I turnt off my laptop. Now I turned it on again and it didn't boot again...now it sais: Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands. I despair of this laptop...

(initramfs) _

Comment: In that case, I'd check the disk, like [panther mentioned in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984313/the-root-filesystem-requires-a-manual-fsck/984321?noredirect=1#comment1583825_984313)

Comment: you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you use `fsck /dev/sda2`; then type <kbd>y</kbd> to any question fsck asks; there must be a space between `fsck` and `/dev`. look keenly at the GNU of your Ubuntu if its /sda1 or sda2 reported having the error. `fsck` the specific `sda` which is reported to be having the error it works!