# Ubuntu 17.04 doesn't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 17.04

I have Ubuntu 17.04 installed alongside Windows 10. grub works well, but Ubuntu does not start and it boots to a black screen with this text.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Comment: run `fsck /dev/sda6`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your disk has a some bad blocks, at the very least.  I would run `fsck -y  /dev/sda6` at the prompt, as the message suggests.