# Unable to boot from system or access desktop

Tags: boot, xubuntu

Short while after installation and kernel update
I get this Error & unable to access desktop.

[image: Unexpected Inconsistency]

In System setup - there's no option to prioritize
Boot device as usual.

[image: Boot from HD only]

My question is: How should I access desktop
or restore the boot prioritize ability?

[Please be specific & detailed as possible]

Comment: Did you actually do what the error message recommends?

Comment: I don't know HOW exactly to apply it. would you kindly instruct me?

Comment: It is described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually

Answer (score 0):

To check/repair the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root` or `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root` or `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Why the sudo if you're in a root shell already?

Comment: @SebastianStark probably habit... but I've seen situations where even though you're in root, some commands that would normally require sudo, post an error/warning message if sudo isn't used, even in root.

Comment: I think it's a bad habit, and those are bad programs :)

Comment: @SebastianStark using sudo in root shell makes no difference... and **what** are bad programs? `fsck` isn't.

Comment: I meant those programs you mentioned that warn you about not using sudo, although you are root already. It makes no (big) difference, but it could give newbies the impression that "for fsck you need sudo"

Comment: @SebastianStark that's one reason that I DO leave sudo in my answers... sudo IS required for `fsck` in other situations... like if you were to want to `fsck` a different unmounted partition, from the `terminal` app.

Comment: Thank you @heynema - I follow the instructions.
How do I choose root access? Its not like previous steps where I have menu..

Comment: @ELDandanKhen just follow my instructions, and it'll take you to root access, where you can do the fsck.

Comment: I'll be more than glad to mark it as it works.. how shall I choose root access? tried to type the commends it didn't bring me further than step 4

Comment: @ELDandanKhen  Don't you get to the # prompt after choosing root access from the menus?

Comment: @heynnema After entering recovery mode I put password and it brings me to the screen in picture 1 -is that the "root access"?

Comment: @ELDandanKhen ah, now I get see the problem. Type **help** or **exit**, or hit the **Enter** key, and then enter the fsck command. You may or may not need the sudo at the beginning of the fsck command. Let me know which fsck command you finally use, and I'll update my instructions for future readers.

Comment: Well - help brought up all possible commands - exit brought up the same error message sudo fsck - /bin/sh: sudo: not found

fsck brings fsck from util-linux 2.27.1 
(infitramfs)

Comment: I wonder how to surpass that error or even fix the boot menu via system setup

Comment: @ELDandanKhen then try the fsck directly at the infitramfs prompt. Report back.

Comment: (initramfs) fsck
fsck fromutil-linux 2.27.1
(initramfs)

Comment: @heynnema not responding further than that.. what else might work?

Comment: @ELDandanKhen I provided a possible alternate way to proceed in my answer. Let me know how it goes.