# UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY - multiple times

Tags: boot, mount, disk, fsck

I got the temporary fix from the solutions to this question:
[fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Real Problem: I get this error many times (got it again while typing this question), and I have to follow that solution again and again.

What exactly is the issue here? Hardware or the software?

OS info:

Linux 4.15.0-29-generic

16.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64
(error persisted even for 18.04)

Comment: Probably hardware, but `journalctl /dev/sda6` will show you more information.

Comment: The output is here: https://gist.github.com/codesome/cc9a772589701bff2b631c184a9fe095, and I dont know how do I make sense out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran (Sept 2, 2021) into this issue in an SSD that I was using to debug Ub20.04 freezing completely. I installed 20.04 froze. Then I installed 18.04 in the same SSD to see if that will run properly since I was blaming snaps for the crash, by the way I removed snaps from this 18.04 install. My original 18.04 in another ssd started having freezing issues when Snaps was added to it.

It turned out to be the video card. Removed it and everything seems fine. When I rebooted 18.04 it did an

> unattended update, don't turn off your computer.

After this I tried to boot into 20.04 and got the message

> fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.

I did from the initfram error screen

```
fsck -fy /dev/sda1
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Everything is fine now. So I blame the playing with the install, not the SSD.

Comment: You may need to format your answer well... especially the "bash" area.