# Laptop is not booting Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, initramfs

I am using Ubuntu (single boot) for 3 years without any major problem. But now I am facing a problem. My laptop is not booting in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS.

When I push the start button, then nothing comes on screen. After pushing any button, then GNU grub window comes & the cursor jump to the fourth line `* Memory test`.

[image: grub window]

By pushing upper arrow, set cursor on Ubuntu & push,  then the below command line appears:

[image: booting]

After waiting for long time same thing exists without booting.
By pusing start button I can power off the laptop. 
Now how can I boot my laptop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boot drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Comment: i have solved my problem from the answer given above