# Error message during start up Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: uefi, startup, fsck

All of a sudden it started showing errors during startup and as I am not a pro user, I couldn't fix it. Can anyone help me regarding this issue?
I have attached the following picture.
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve that issue is to boot to another Linux (you need to prepare Live USB with Ubuntu) and then open terminal and execute following:

```
fsck /dev/sda2
```

Comment: Thanks @Gravemind. May I know the actual reason for this error?
Moreover, from this question [https://askubuntu.com/a/697197/883195] I got this answer. Nevertheless, every time it is showing during the start up although finally I can run Ubuntu now with the help of (fsck /dev/sda2).