# Firmware Bug? and unexpected inconsistancy

Tags: boot, lenovo, fsck, ideapad

I have had been having issues with Windows 10 continuously becoming corrupted, and got fed up and installed Ubuntu 18.04. For a while things were going great, however when I went to boot my computer today I was met with the lines of code shown below.

```
[   0.099372] AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug] : : IOAPIC [4] not in IVRS table
[   0.099375] AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug] : : IOAPIC [5] not in IVRS table
[   0.099377] AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug] : : No southbridge IOAPIC found
[   0.099378] AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
[   1.002681] AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter
[   1.171745] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xbf7a6000-0xbf7a9fff]
[   1.211576] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found

/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY
         (i.e., without -a or 0p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Comment: Think maybe you should backup your data and maybe think of getting a new hard drive.

Comment: I purchased the laptop from best buy, and I took it to geek squad. They claimed the hard drive or any other hardware was not the issue, however, I have had what appear to be software issues with running windows 10. All geek squad was capbible of doing was reinstalling windows from a boot disk, and a day, to a week after picking up the computer I would experinece crashes again, and error codes that implied corruptions in the software. I'm really frustrated with this computer, and I was hopeing that my computer just had trouble running windows, and I optimistically installed ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, so I followed karels link. and typed in the following code

Comment: Look up how to run a SMART test on your hard drive.

Comment: I ran  the code fsck /dev/sda2   and said yes to all.  I then rebooted the system, and ubuntu did indeed load.  So I'm back into my computer. If anyone has anyidea what might have caused this issue, and can explain it to me I would appreciate it.

Comment: I would also suggesting searching for any BIOS or disk firmware updates on the net. New computer? Contact the mfgr and ask them. Run disk diagnostics. Cheaper than paying BB Geek Squad for service would be to buy small SSD. Use latest Clonezilla live to dup drive.

Comment: Run the `gsmartcontrol-root` command as `root`, select the problematic disk (`/dev/sda`?) and look at the **Error Log** tab!

Comment: I have yet to check into the BIOS or firmware updates, I however did get some acquaintance with the gsmartcontrol tool. gsmartcontrol says that overall my disk is okay, but under the attributes section it flagged some reallocated sector counts, which I learned is indicative of disk surface failures. The error log seems to be empty, but I will continue to check back for any further information. I will also run some disk scans to see what they come up with. The original error code has also occurred several more times now, but I least I can get passed it. Thank you all very much for your help!