# Ubuntu won't reboot after fsck fix

Tags: reboot, fsck

I got a fsck error same as this post [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually) and followed their suggestions. It seems like it ran fine but nothing happens when I type "reboot". I don't know if it's safe to force my computer to shut down with the power button, or if that will cause more issues?

This is how I found my computer after coming back to it after lockdowns - I don't know what happened, but I assume it didn't shut down properly. I had left it on so I would be able to access it remotely, but that stopped working a couple of months ago.

Edit: I should also say it's waiting for input with "(initramfs)" at the front (where I'd normally expect to see my username/folder location/etc - I don't know what that's called).

Comment: `shutdown -r now` doesn't work?

Comment: if you can't shutdown via command (Terrance's comment), next I'd use SysRq keys to tell the linux kernel to shutdown/reboot/other...  REISUB etc will ensure no negative consequences...

Comment: I can't use shutdown, it says "sh: shutdown: not found"
I edited my initial question to hopefully give more useful information as I don't know what I'm looking at

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Del from a tty will reboot the machine, maybe give that a go?

Comment: Hey look at that! Thank you, ctrl-alt-del worked. It seems obvious now, but I didn't want to make more problems for myself when I didn't know what was going on

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ginnungagap for the answer that solved it for me: Ctrl-alt-del

Restarted my computer and it started up without any issues.