# Why am I getting this screen all of a sudden when I turn my Laptop on?

Tags: 18.04

I'm not even sure what or how to Google this. I'm getting this error on a black screen when I power on my laptop and select Ubuntu from the grub menu.

I'm running Linux 18.04 LTS on a dual-booted machine (ASUS). The Linux is on an external hard disk (sdb). Windows 10 is on sda

```
T.SE4585) tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug): ACFI region dnes t saer
ntire command./response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f f1Ag ÚGE1) ve fe.964599) tpm_crb MSF TO101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not coVEr
E Pntire tommand/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flag T1] ve fe2.424212] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb) No Caching mode page found
2.424257] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb) ASsuming drive cache: write through
2.428540] scsi 2:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
2.428566] scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
2.428586] scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19dev/sdb2: Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
dev/sdb2: Run journal anyway/dev/sdb2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
(i.e., without -a or -p options)fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sdb2 requires a manual fsckBusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.(initramfs)
```

Comment: Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually).

Comment: @kashish The method mentioned in the Answer at the link you shared worked! Thank you! If you'd like to put your comment in the Answer box, I'd gladly accept it as the answer for this question.

Comment: @kashish Yes. It solved my error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @kashish in the comments, [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)'s Answer is the solution to my problem.

Here's a summary:

`fsck /dev/sda6` (where /dev/sda6 is the partition mentioned)

And enter Yes `y` for each error question. Or press `a` one time `fsck -a /dev/sda6`  for always-yes.

Then reboot and it should be fine.