# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS won't boot. BusyBox (initrams) pops up instead. What to do?

Tags: dual-boot, initramfs, nvidia-geforce, busybox

After turning on my laptop the Ubuntu logo appeared for some seconds and then the BusyBox (initrams) console popped up.

[image: Error-message]

It shows an `ACPI` and a `PKCS#7` error message.

I have read in some forums that the PKCS#7 message is related to the Nvidia graphic card but I don't know how to fix it. Any idea?

Thank you.

More info:

My laptop is an Asus N56V. It has an intel core i7 3rd generation and an Nvidia GeForce GT 635M.

It has dual boot with windows 8.

Comment: Try to start an older kernel. Or deactivate secure boot in efi menu.

Comment: Is this a new install? Or did it 'used to work'?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: It used to work. I think it happened after an improper shutdown when it ran out of battery. But it's fixed now. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now.

I just typed `exit` and hit 'enter'.

It displayed something like

`/dev/sda8: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.`

among many other lines. Then I ran `fsck /dev/sda8` and typed `y` for each input request until the `(initramfs)` was displayed again. Then `reboot` and enter.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)