# What could be the cause of an "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY" error?

Tags: boot, steam

A couple of days ago I got the error:

```
UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY
```

when rebooting my 20.04 machine. The last thing I did before rebooting was running some game in Steam, the game tried to open a link in a web browser and that failed and I think the game crashed, iirc. After that, Steam just gave me a black screen, so I rebooted and got this error.

**I am not asking how to reboot successfully**, since I fscked manually, but what could be the cause? I am ruling out a hard drive error since the SSD is only a year old and SMART seems to be fine:

[image]

(By the way, I am not taking that 99C temp as accurate, it has always said that, must be a bug in reading the temp of the drive).

The partition that gave the error was /dev/sdc6, which is /home.

What could be the cause of the UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY error? I am guessing Steam did something, but is it possible that it would cause such an error?

Comment: @karel the top answer there helped me reboot, but not diagnose the issue. However, this answer is useful - https://askubuntu.com/a/822451/684141 - especially this part - "My opinion is that there is [a] serious problem in Ubuntu with regard to SSD disks. The community should fix it. I have found a possible cause of this problem: probably the system did not shutdown normally." The system indeed did not shut down normally. I think the issue was caused by Steam messing something up.

Comment: That's the answer I read too.