# USB install on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on USB and have been having all kinds of problems I went as far as disabiling acpi and using boot repair utility to try and install the os to the flash drive I will post pictures of the errors I keep getting after I get error about not being able to mount file system “/“ it hangs and just sits there.

It says

```
ext4-fs (SDc3): vis: cannot find ext4 file system 
/target wrong ts type, bad option, bad superblock on dev/sdc3, missing codepage or helper program,
```

or other error and

```
  xdg_runtime is not owned by us (UID 0)but by UID 999! This could eg 
happen if you try to connect to a non-root pulseAstudio as a root user, over 
the native protocol. Don’t do that.
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Installing Ubuntu to USB using an **image file** can not fail, unless there is something physically wrong. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi

Comment: I have tried micro usb flash drives, regular flash drives and my sd card slot and it is still saying the same thing I have 4 2 tb flash drives and 4 micro sd cards that are 1tb a piece.. right now it’s saying rtw_pci failed to send h2c command

Comment: I was referring to install method not install medium. Sudodus, the creator of mkusb, made a perfect install to a USB drive, then he made an image file from the USB drive. My link shows how to create a USB drive from this image. Have you tried booting a different computer from the USB's you have made? What tool did you use to make your installer drive? Etcher, Rufus, UNetbootin?

Comment: I’ve tried unetbootin and Rufus not etcher yet though I’ll try the usb install file you linked thanks for the link to the file to download! I’ll report back progress

Comment: Please let us know how it works for you.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/vcwnf8DV

Comment: That’s what I get now not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: That error looks like you need to run a fschk, perhaps because the drive got unplugged while writing: https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually There are a few things that can go wrong with a bootable USB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot

Comment: Finally got it to work, it won’t update now though it’s saying this... https://postimg.cc/06nHbxgR

Comment: Currently running fsck again it was saying there was 7 illegal blocks all I did was try to resize the partition to 1tb on the running system don’t know why it’s being a pain

Comment: I am able to boot into Ubuntu again but all the apps don’t open ie Firefox system settings the only thing that opens is terminal folders menu and the WiFi screen and sound drop down the settings are not accessible and I’m not able to update the system at all

Answer (score 0):

It’s working now kept getting the h2c unable to pair or send command text and left it on all night then came back restarted the system and the Ubuntu booted up I think it’s a WiFi card problem but seems to be working fine now thanks for all the help!