# DMAR Firmware bug on dead screen HP laptop

Tags: boot, firmware

I am using an 99% dead screen old HP laptop running on ubuntu 20.04 with an external monitor.  Today morning when I tried to boot my system, it shows an error-
"DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this"

I can read this line only on my laptop screen as the screen is almost dead in the below portion. And the external monitor don't work before complete booting up.

I have read this solution [DMAR firmware bug. Broken BIOS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331090/dmar-firmware-bug-broken-bios) but I am still confused as I need to type the command blindly.
What can I do now? Anyone can help please?
Thanks

Comment: Many laptops have the capacity to switch modes from internel/external/internal+external-mirror/internal+external-beside/etc.. via a fn+key toggle. This is done in firmware; ie. if your firmware allows for it it'll work. It's commonly available on dell/hp/lenovo esp. enterprise grade (often missing on cheaper consumer models).  That's what I'd use.  Firmware is a hardware issue, as Ubuntu is only involved once it's booted.