# [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu, firmware

Unfortunately, after a full battery discharge, my laptop (Asus Zenbook running with Kubuntu) had a major problem. At startup, the two following messages appear:

- [Firmware Bug] No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR
- [Firmware Bug] ACPI region does not cover the response buffer

The laptop boots but cannot be used since the screen is completely fuzzy

After multiple attempts (`fsck` on the partitions, complete Kubuntu reinstallation without any success), I have read in this site [DMAR firmware bug. Broken BIOS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331090/dmar-firmware-bug-broken-bios) the possibility of adding two lines in the grub:

```
intremap=no_x2apic_optout nox2apic.
acpi=off if the system starts complaining about ACPI.
```

I've tried but this doesn't work when updating the grub. It's possible that my syntax was incorrect.

Below, find the grub file, could you tell me if somethings could be improved?

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intremap=no_x2apic_optout nox2apic"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console


acpi=off

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416935/ubuntu-22-04-firmware-bug-no-firmware-reserved-region-can-cover-this-rmm

Answer (score 0):

While booting up into 20.04 from an external USB hard-disk on my Lenovo T420 I received firmware Bug announcement referring to no caching page found etc.

I then shutdown (long-press on power button) and ran Ubuntu 20.04 installed on the laptop. As a sudo-user I ran fsck to check the USB drive's file-system status. The /boot file-system needed the dirty-bit cleaned. The remaining file-systems were all OK.

After a clean shutdown and reboot from the external USB drive I was able to enter and update the residing Ubuntu 20.04.

So, maybe worth checking the integrity of a drive's file-systems first before investigating other possibilities. The firmware Bug indication made no hint of a file-system problem. It could be argued that the hard-power-off action may have well caused damaged to the /boot region but after cleaning there was no firmware Bug error reported.

Peter