# Ubuntu 22.04: Firmware Bug no firmware reserved region can cover this RMM

Tags: 22.04, firmware

I get these errors on booting.

[image]

Are these errors serious? How can I fix them?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391559/firmware-bug-no-firmware-reserved-region-can-cover-this-rmrr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are these errors serious?

Not really. It means your BIOS is reporting things the kernel does not understand. Often ACPI related and probably no working hibernation/suspend. I used to have them too but my ssd is so quick I nowadays do not bother with hibernation/suspend anymore.

> How can I fix them?

See the first line: contact your BIOS vendor for fixes. A BIOS update can fix this. The second option would be to report these against the kernel used if this has not happened already (probably is ;) ) and wait for a fix.

Comment: Keep in mind also: **not all vendors ship a complete set of instructions for ACPI** and that leads to erroneous kernel errors sometimes where it doesn't affect anything but just spits an error out.  I see this often on HP, Acer, and Asus boards in their own systems where the BIOS doesn't cover everything ACPI.  But those systems work fine.

Comment: In this case, what is happening is that the ACPI is conflicting with the e820 service. An RMMR (Reserved Memory Region Reporting) is an area of the physical address space that the kernel is requested to identity-map in the DMA remapping IOMMU (DMAR is DMA remapping). RMMRs should pair with e820 (the memory map service) firmware reserved ranges (eg: memory used to emulate legacy devices in SMM). The OS won't use fw reserved region, so it's ok to identity-map them (read: not protected) but if the region is not reserved the OS will use it and will want to protect it (read: may not map it).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to hibernation/suspension, it's more likely that some device won't work when DMA remapping is enabled. But it's hard to tell. That region starts at ~1.9GiB, it seems pretty arbitrary for the firmware to put some data there (unless the machine has 2GiB of memory).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple way:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then add this line in "grub" file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mce=off loglevel=3"
```

Save "grub" file and do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And:

```
reboot
```

Comment: Hi, does this solution solve the problem or hidden?

Comment: Hi Mohammad! This solution does not solve the problem but hides.

Answer (score -1):

For those who encounter similar issues like "Ubuntu xx.xx: Firmware Bug no firmware reserved region can cover this RMM" (but the following messages may differ) after re-installing the Ubuntu, check if you've formatted the partition for root (`/`) during installation.

For some who are curious, if you've made dedicated partitions for some mount points like `/home`, you can keep the data for re-installation. Of course, it makes little sense that you keep the kernel. In my case, due to incompatible issue of a software, I have to downgrade from 22.04 to 20.04 but I forgot to format the partition for root (`/`).

Answer (score -1):

enter BIOS and disable Intel RST (turn it off or switch it to AHCI)