# Update HP Bios on Ubuntu LTS

Tags: hp, bios

```
DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x000000009d800000-0x000000009fffffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
```

Ubuntu LTS is my main OS, i do not have dualboot.
Im using an HP laptop.

Okay, my apologies,
i reached out to HP about this message, and they suggested a power drain and update the bios. i don't have a windows operating system and so they referred me here. Should i create a separate partition and download windows to update the bios? or is there another way to do the update? my laptop runs fine, when i turn on the laptop i see that message and if i can fix it id like, just need to know a way you'd recommend doing this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Just reporting the error is not sufficient and this question is not answerable. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1508108/edit) and add more relevant information. When do you see this error? If you do something that makes this error appear, state what exactly you do, the commands you enter before you get this error. What happens after this error appears? Does the computer work after the error appears? Which version of Ubuntu LTS are you using? Answer all these questions inside your question. Please provide a question title that describes the problem.

Comment: contact BIOS vendor for fixes ,,,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04: Firmware Bug no firmware reserved region can cover this RMM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416935/ubuntu-22-04-firmware-bug-no-firmware-reserved-region-can-cover-this-rmm)

Comment: Also see [UEFI update from UBUNTU - Acer Aspire 5 A515-54](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436388/uefi-update-from-ubuntu-acer-aspire-5-a515-54) for a way to do BIOS update when you don't have Windows installed. Alternately wait for the release of Ubuntu 24.04. The newer kernel in the new version of Ubuntu may fix it.

Comment: "my laptop runs fine" if it aint broken....  2nd: it depends on the bios. some bips let you select a file from (often from  fat32 partition,and that could be an usb stick). But my opinion: don't. you can brick your system.  if you don't want to see message during you can also suppress those with a `loglevel 3` before `quit` in grub conf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dmar-firmware-bug-broken-bios](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331090/dmar-firmware-bug-broken-bios)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DMAR firmware bug. Broken BIOS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331090/dmar-firmware-bug-broken-bios)