# DMAR: [firmware bug] : no firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x0000000068800000 - 0x000000006affffff], contact bios vendors for fixes

Tags: boot, firmware

I get the following error when rebooting, any ideas of how to solve it?

```
[    0.164437] DMAR: [firmware bug] : no firmware reserved region can cover this
RMRR [0x0000000068800000 - 0x000000006affffff], contact bios vendors for fixes
[    0.188442] x86/cpu: SGX disable by bios
[    1.986351] 
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs. "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):_
```

[This is the picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7V8U.jpg)

Comment: Press ctrl+d. What happens afterward?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DMAR firmware bug. Broken BIOS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331090/dmar-firmware-bug-broken-bios)