# *Continuous* 'file system with errors' issue. What does it indicate?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, fsck

Edit: adding Disks Screenshot as recomended.

[image]

There are other threads on this issue. However, they don't have clarity as to why this problem keeps repeating.

I'll define the problem.

On switching on the laptop, I am given something similar to this error, (borrowing from the user - Jordy)

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda6 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda6: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda6 requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

Despite following the steps listed in the big thread [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually) , involving the use of **fsck**, the problem repeats after rebooting. I am able to type this question as this one time the problem did not repeat.

As per the linked thread, this is indicative of:

1. Failing Hard Drive, as per the user - gammapoint
   or
2. System not shutting down properly, as per the user - farmuel Angel

The above thread is close to six years old. What is the current known reason?
I understand that, anyway, backups are essential. However, if the reason for these errors is determined, one can take steps to resolve. For example:

a. do I need a new hard drive

b. do I need to check memory

c. is this a temporary issue that happens some 7 - 10 times, is resolved by fsck and doesn't appear again ...

- As per the 'Disks' program -

> Disk is OK, 16 bad sectors (43° C / 109° F)

I thank you in anticipation of an urgent answer, so I can proceed with my work. Regards.

P.S: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Only Ubuntu. I have one in-built hard-drive.

Comment: There is not enough information about the errors you are seeing. While copying from others may seem like a viable option, it leaves out details that are specific to your system. You may find the errors you see within the log files in `/var/log`. Generally file system warnings are a sign that something isn’t right and should not be ignored. Do you have other operating systems on your computer along with Ubuntu? Which version of Ubuntu are you running? What type of storage device are you booting from? More information about *your machine* is needed to offer possible answers 

Comment: I am in the folder var/log, what information should I get from there? 

I am using purely Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The storage device is the inbuilt hard drive. I have only one. Kindly let me know.

Comment: This is what I could find through checking other forums: if this is what you need, I will add it to the main question. Advise.

Log of fsck -C -a -T -t ext4 /dev/sda2 
Fri Nov  5 06:12:28 2021

/dev/sda2: clean, 579919/60760064 files, 97732025/243038464 blocks

Fri Nov  5 06:12:29 2021

Comment: Does this systematically happen after reboot, even after you succesfully repaired the drive on the Initramfs prompt? (`fsck -y /dev/sda6`). If this is recurrent, then, yes, expect a hardware problem.

Comment: in my case it was fsck -y dev/sda2  (the above image is an example from another user). It has not happened the last 2 times. Before that, I can safely say - ten times.

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? Edit your question and show me a screenshot of the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** data window. Resize the window so that the screenshot captures all of the data. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: You didn't say if you dual-boot with Windows. You didn't give me the screenshot that I requested. I also need to see `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: @heynnema adding image to my question right now. Kindly read the comment to your answer below.

Comment: Unfortunately you’re out of support with 16.04 LTS and therefore off topic - which is a shame as your question is well written! It’s probably time to upgrade your os and then you’ll also find out if a fresh installation (eg 20.04 LTS) resolve the problem.

Comment: @Will I have 8 gb ram and 2-4 cores i5 (4th generation). I make music. Will 20.04 be heavier than 16.04 and cause speed issues ?

Comment: @katya sehgal - I can’t say 100%, but I think you’ll be fine. I gave my son my old computer which isn’t a dissimilar spec, & it works fine on 20.04LTS (it was too old to run windows 10 properly). Give it a go with a live usb session - that’ll test all your hardware (except the hd) is up to it.

Answer (score 1):

**File system check/repair...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Bad block scan...**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sda2` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually mentioned above I use purely Ubuntu (no windows). I had followed the fsck steps, at boot itself without using Live USB. Currently no boot issue. But have 16 bad sectors as per DISKS. Screenshot - https://postimg.cc/p9Rq0Gys  Wrote sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX in terminal - "  /dev/sda2 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.  "

Comment: Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1050624 1945358335 1944307712 927.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1945358336 1953523711    8165376   3.9G Linux swap

Comment: @katyasehgal You **must** boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to perform the fsck and bad blocking on your disk. The correct command to bad block is `sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sda2`.

Comment: @katyasehgal Status please. You also never showed me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: @katyasehgal Status please...

Comment: Excuse the delay. I did not have the live cd. I am now installing ubuntu 20.04 (on a new hard disk), and will then use the command to repair (if possible) the earlier hard disk with errors.  This time, i have prepared an Ubuntu Live USB to avoid problem in future. Kindly allow to update again