# Ubuntu boot failed and said that x86 CPU SGX disabled by BIOS

Tags: boot, server, java, minecraft

Yesterday,I opened my server as usual.I was playing Minecraft:Java Edition on my server.I have built my house for over 3 hours.However,the connection suddenly stopped.I tried to reboot my server,but when it was booting,it said that `x86/CPU: SGX disabled by BIOS` I tried to reset my BIOS,but it never works. When I tried to enter my Ubuntu 20.0.4LTS desktop through recovery mode,it said [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9ZZL.jpg).It will be my friend's birthday tomorrow and I planned to give him a surprise on Minecraft.So I need help immediately.Thanks for help

Comment: Did you run what it is saying to do in the image you posted?  It is telling you that you need to run `fsck -f /dev/sda2` or run `fsck -fy /dev/sda2` for automatic repairs of the partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Comment: Found a link to the discussion about this. Not sure if it will help you.
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=358981