# Why is my OS asking me to do manual fsck all the time?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, fsck

Everytime I turn on my Xubuntu system, it asks me to do a manual `fsck`.

Is there something wrong with my system?

Should I be concerned?

Comment: Sometimes there's a problem; sometimes there's not. There are many possible reasons for asking to do a manual fsck. Some of those reasons are beyond your control (like power loss), some are due to poor user habits (like holding down the power button), some are due to bugs in the software, the kernel, or your hardware/firmware. If it's frequent, review your habits and your logs for clues.

Comment: It would help if you could include an image of the exact error message - this may have been answered here before.

Comment: How are you shutting down your system normally? How many filesystems do you have? Please, [edit] your question and add this information together with the output of `df -hT | grep -v tmpfs`.

Comment: sorry guys. I should have and will add more info. I shut the system using shutdown -P. thanks by the way.

Comment: @karel thanks karel but unfortunately no. It does not say why this happens and if there is something that I should be concerned with or it is just the version of my os that is problematic

Answer (score 0):

*UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY means there is some file system error in the disk. Run the `fsck` command manually. After that it will ask some more questions. Just answer y and press Enter and finally reboot the computer.* <sup>[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/858434/)</sup>

Solving a small problem by running `fsck` when you get the RUN fsck MANUALLY message will prevent a possible big problem later on. Ubuntu is shouting at you in capital letters to do something small by running fsck which is printed in small letters to prevent a possible bigger problem later on. It's good advice. I would take it.