# The root filesystem on /dev/sdx# requires a manual fsck

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have installed windows and Ubuntu 22.04 on my computer but when I boot and go to Ubuntu it is giving some problems - may lie only with the primary block group descriptors, and the backup block group descriptors may be OK.

```
/dev/sda4: Block bitmap for group 64 is not in group. (block 1162627398)
/dev/sda4: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY. (i.e., without -a or -p options) fsck exited with status code 4 The root filesystem on /dev/sda4 requires a manual fsck
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Comment: See the duplicate linked. The error is telling you to run `fsck /dev/sda4` at the initframfs prompt. This occurs when a file system error has been detected. Common causes are not properly shutting down or a failing hard drive