# Issues with startup

Tags: boot, command-line, busybox

my computer won't start up.  It gets stuck part way and gives this message in terminal:

```
[   0.197384] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

It might be related to the fact that I recently tried to upgrade my audio drivers, and in doing so tried to enroll an mok, which I have no idea how to.

Can someone please help me get my computer started up?

I typed exit, and now this is what it showed:

```
/dev/sdd1 contains a file system with errors, check forced. Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sdd1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. (i.e., without -a or -p options)

fsck exited with status code 4 The root filesystem on /dev/sdd1 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

Comment: As *drivers* are actually kernel modules, and thus can be expected to impact booting (linux is the closest part of the stack to your hardware) providing specific details as to what you did would be helpful (as well as OS/release details; your `busybox` reads as *jammy* to me but it's best if we're told that detail!), let alone the MOK specifics as to your change(s).  We're guessing otherwise, or limited to generic answers (*that may not always be helpful*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/q/697190/)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.  I used fsck, and it worked!  Praise God!