# Fsck problem: the root filesystem on /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck

Tags: fsck

My Ubuntu computer says
/dev/sda5 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda5:
Inode 393249 seems to contain garbage.

/dev/sda5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
(i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
the root filesystem on /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.4) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)

How do I fix this?

Comment: Boot from **another** linux system, typically from a USB drive with Ubuntu running live 'Try Ubuntu'; Identify the problematic drive, if it is still seen as `/dev/sda5` and run `sudo e2fsck -cf /dev/sda5` and if there are lots of error messages maybe according to the automatic advice `sudo e2fsck -p /dev/sda5`; See more details at `man e2fsck`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Comment: It says sudo not found.

Comment: If you boot from an Ubuntu USB drive, there is sudo. Do not try this from the system that you want to repair.

Answer (score 0):

At the prompt enter `fsck -y /dev/sda5` to run manual check on the filesystem. The `-y` option will automatically answer yes to all question.