# Fsck error after resize my Ubuntu partition on Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, initramfs, fsck, resize

I use Windows and Ubuntu on my PC with dual boot and I resize my Ubuntu partition on Windows. After restarting I got an error with fsck. I can't fix it. Help me

```
/dev/nvme0n1p4: The filesystem size ( according to the super block) is 39321533 blocks
Either the super block or the partiton  table is likely to be correpted!

/dev/nvme0n1p4: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
      (i.e., without -a or - p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p4 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.30.1 ( ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (shh)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Comment: The error message says "*requires a manual fsck*", have you booted *live* media & performed that `fsck` or file-system check  (do note: the command you require may not be `fsck` depending on your chosen file-system, so use whatever command matches your *fs*)

Comment: There might be no fix. ...who resizes an ext4 partition on Windows???