# Repair a Ubuntu server installation after power fluctuation

Tags: boot, root, mdadm, data-corruption, raid5

I have an ubuntu server that includes a 256GB SSD as the boot device and 3 6TB SATA HDDs as a mdadm software RAID5 array.

While it was up and running we had an electrical service interruption that rapidly yet irregularly pulsed on and off for several seconds until finally staying on. Upon checking the server which was set to reboot automatically after power loss, I got the following message on screen:

```
 /dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
    Inodes that were part of a corruped orphan linked list found.
    
    /dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
    fsck exited with status code 4
    The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck
    
    
    BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1.4) built-in shell (ash)
    Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
    
    (initramfs) _
```

Obviously I want to repair the boot device corruption as well a save all data on the RAID5 array. No I hadn't got around to building the backup computer yet. Was still on my to do list pending budget allowance. Yeah I know!!!

I booted up with a Linux Mint 20.3 Live USB drive and couldn't find much of the servers data via the file explorer. But then I'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to Linux installations and any recovery options.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

TIA

Addendum (2023-07-05): Additional information

OK, first of all, the solution is generic. It doesn't mention anything about a software RAID5 array, which the OS probably didn't take into consideration and is my prime concern. I was hoping for someone to help that once happened to be in the 'exact' same situation. I would imagine that saving a 'server' with a 12TB RAID array would be first in everyone's mind, not fixing errors on the boot drive. Second I have no idea how to run the command in terminal if I can't get into the OS. Once some years ago, someone helped me use chroot and other such commands from a live linux CDROM to repair GRUB on a linux partition, but I can't remember exactly what was done, nor if it'd be a viable solution in this particular case.  My fear is that I'd have to know something more before doing as it said to save the RAID5 array information.  I don't even know if the mdadm RAID configuration data is on the boot drive or embedded in the RAID array itself, or what to look for.

Also If I'm breaking some sort of posting rules, this type interface is completely new to me.

Again thanks for any help that will allow me to understand how I need to proceed to ensure I can save the Software RAID configuration data.

Comment: Not sure what kind of "any help" is needed. Have you done what it says to do - "RUN fsck MANUALLY"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, but my main concern is saving the software mdadm RAID5 array configuration data, and I don't know how to run fsck if I can't boot the OS.