# When booting to ubuntu acpi bios error appears

Tags: dual-boot, bios, acpi

Please provide me solution for the error showed in below attached image.
FYI,i dual booted with win 11 and ubuntu.
[Error screen for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuvTT.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)