# sh: fsck/dev/sda10: not found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, error-handling, boot-partition

I got into a problem while trying to boot Ubuntu similar to that of the one in the question I've linked below,

[fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

But when I try to run `fsck/dev/sda10`,

It shows `sh: fsck/dev/sda10: not found`

(The partition that required fsck was indeed `sda10`)

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't see a space between the command and the devicename, it should be `fsck /dev/sda10`

Comment: Ohh thank you so much! My bad, I didn't know the commands were sensitive to space.