# ACPI BIOS Error (Bug): UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY and problem loading x.509 certificate -65

Tags: 22.04, bios, fsck

I got the following error while I was working on my Ubuntu 22.04. How to resolve it?

[image: error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)